# Perform multiple command on 1000 remote servers?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have the scenario to perform multiple linux commands on 1000 servers(linux) for the auditing purpose.What i feel is ssh & copying key to the remote hosts are bit tough to do on all the 1000-1500 server. Is there is any possibility to achieve that.
   In fact i heard some where about rcmd command utility.But i'm not able to find the exact work done.

Regards,
Sarvan

Comment: If you need to do this frequently you might want look into saltstack and similar tools. I mean managing more than 1 box should not be done manually...

Comment: Hi fejese , thanks for your prompt reply ... and if i get any advice about rcmd command it would be helpful & I may get any solution !!

Comment: Maybe look into [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). You probably might not want to use [rsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsh) for security reasons (prefer `ssh`). You definitely have some way to access these remote servers (for the first time), so use it.

Comment: Your question is off-topic and imprecise. How do you access to these many hosts in the first place? Where did you get them? What services are running on them?

Comment: Need to fire some commands on each remote machine like ....dmidecode , pciscan , snmpd status , clustat .... & required the consolidated information for the auditing purpose ..

Comment: In fact we have all the machine IP addresses, username & password to login ... have to automate the same procedure on the each machines ... feels copying of ssh key to all the machines looks impossible.

Comment: perhaps better suited over @ http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give a try for "sshrun" script. It takes a list of servers in a text file and run the commands from another text file.  I have used that script for a similar maintenance purpose for a bunch of servers. It is able to use commands needing "sudo" at the destination.

http://www.homelinuxpc.com/download/sshrun_user_guide.pdf

http://www.homelinuxpc.com/download/sshrun.tar.gz

You may need also "autopass" if you need to type password for each server:

http://www.homelinuxpc.com/download/autopass_user_guide.pdf

http://www.homelinuxpc.com/download/autopass.tar.gz

That "autopass" is a combined bash/expect script. It asks password once and whenever remote server is asking password it will respond with that password.  "autopass" can be used to run that "sshrun" to avoid typing password manually for example 1000 times.

Comment: Hi Ajaaskel, thanks for your feedback , Kindly have the scenario here... we have the diffreent IP ranges & different username & different password for each sites to login . In fact we have to do this task on 40 geographical site servers.

Comment: That will be really pain to do but I don't know any work around. After you have your ssh key on each and every server everything will be better and you can collect dmidecode, etc. very quickly from all of them.